# error en la variable date

Tags: python, mvc, xml, odoo

Estoy tratando de descargar el reporte del popup que es para informes avanzados es decir que va abstraer cierta información dependiendo de la selección que se haga en este caso yo tengo tres opciones ya sea general o por empleado o por destino el reporte general si me esta imprimiendo la información tanto en la consola como en el reporte pero al seleccionar por empleado solo me muestra la información en la consola pero no me descarga el reporte pero si me muestra la información en la pantalla pero no me descarga el reporte y en este caso la funcion del seleccionar por empleado es que me muestre los registros con un empleado en especifico y me muestra en la consola todos los registros a nombre de un solo empleado y no solo los del empleado

Adjunto código del modelo:

```
import json
import io
from xlsxwriter import workbook
from datetime import date
from odoo.tools import date_utils
from odoo import fields, models, api
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
try:
from odoo.tools.misc import xlsxwriter
except ImportError:
import xlsxwriter


class SaleReportAdvance(models.TransientModel):
_name = "sale_report_general"

from_date = fields.Date(string="Fecha de cotizacion")
to_date = fields.Date(string='Vencimiento')
type = fields.Selection(
    [('General', 'General'), ('Executive', 'Executive'), ('Country', 'Country')],
    string='Buscar por', default='General', reqired=True)
seller_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='hr.employee', string='Ejecutivo')
country_arrival = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.country', string='Destino')

def _get_data(self):
    sale = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '!=', 'cancel')])
    validity_date = date.today()

    if self.from_date and self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() >= self.from_date and x.date_order.date() <= self.to_date,
                                  sale))
    elif not self.from_date and not self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() <= validity_date,
                                  sale))
    else:
        sales_order = sale

    logger.info('**********sales_order*** {0}****'.format(sales_order))

    result = []
    seller = []
    country = []
    for rec in self.seller_id:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        seller.append(a)
        logger.info('**********seller*** {0}****'.format(seller))
    for rec in self.country_arrival:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        country.append(a)
        logger.info('**********country*** {0}****'.format(country))

    logger.info('*******Selecciono general %s ****' % self.type)
    if self.type == 'General':
        for so in sales_order:
            logger.info('**********result*** %s****' % so.date_order)

            if so.date_order:
                    res = {
                        'name': so.name,
                        'date': so.date_order,
                        'partner': so.partner_id.name,
                        'validity': so.validity_date,
                        'consignee': so.consignee_id.name,
                        'seller': so.seller_id.name,
                        'country': so.country_arrival.name,
                        'freight': so.freight_type,
                        'gross': so.gross_weight,
                        'volume': so.volume,
                        'invoice': so.invoice_amount_assured,
                        'cotiza': so.name,
                    }
                    result.append(res)
                    logger.info('**********result*** {0}****'.format(result))

    logger.info('*******Selecciono executive %s ****' % self.type)
    if self.type == 'Executive':
        for so in sales_order:
            logger.info('***********seller*****{0}*****'.format(seller))

            if so.date_order:
                res = {
                    'name': so.name,
                    'date': so.date_order,
                    'partner': so.partner_id.name,
                    'validity': so.validity_date,
                    'consignee': so.consignee_id.name,
                    'country': so.country_arrival.name,
                    'freight': so.freight_type,
                    'gross': so.gross_weight,
                    'volume': so.volume,
                    'invoice': so.invoice_amount,
                    'cotiza': so.name,
                }
                result.append(res)
                logger.info('**********seller*** {0}****'.format(result))
    data = {
        'ids': self,
        'model': 'sale_report_general',
        'form': result,
        'seller_id': seller,
        'country_arrival': country,
        'type': self.type,
        'no_value': False
    }
    return data


def get_ventas_report(self):
    data = self._get_data()
    logger.info('**************Obtuvo el informe de ventas')
    return self.env.ref('sale_report_terrestre.action_general_report').report_action(self, data=data)

    if self.date_order and self.validity_date and not self.seller_id and not self.country_arrival:
        data['no_value'] = True
        return data
```

asi es como estoy estructurando el modelo pero que cambios tendria que hacer en la parte de executive para que solome muestre los registros de un empleado en especifico y no me muestre todos y solo los sustituya por el empleado que estyo buscando y en cuestion del reporte el error no lo muestra en la terminal si no solo en la interfaz de odoo

odoo.addons.base.models.qweb.QWebException: 'date'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/odoo14.0/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 331, in _compiled_fn
return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
File "", line 1, in template_sale_report_terrestre_sales_general_view_276
File "", line 2, in body_call_content_274
File "", line 1, in foreach_261
KeyError: 'date'

Error to render compiling AST
KeyError: 'date'
Template: sale_report_terrestre.sales_general_view
Path: /t/t/div/div[1]/t[2]/table/t/tr/td[1]/span
Node:

ese es el error que esta mandando en la interfaz

adjunto código del reporte

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<template id="sales_general_view">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
       <div class="header" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
           <h3 class="text-center">Sales General Report
               <span style="font-size: 14px;"><storng>From</storng>:<t t-esc="date"/> <strong>To</strong>: <t t-esc="date"/></span>
           </h3>
           <div class="article mt0 o_report_layout_standard">
               <t t-if="type == 'General'">
                     <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <th style="width:30%">Date</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Folio</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Remitente</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Consignatario</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Destino</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Volumen</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Peso_Bruto</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Seguro</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Factura</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Monto Fact</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Vencimineto</th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Ejecutivo</th>
                       </thead>
                        <t t-foreach="form" t-as="order">
                         <tr>
                           <td><span t-esc="order['date']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['name']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['partner']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['consignee']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['country']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['volume']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['gross']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['freight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['freight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['invoice']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['validity']"/></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="order['seller']"/></td>
                          </tr>
                        </t>
                    </table>
               </t>
               <t t-if="type == 'Executive'">
                 <h3>
                    <span style="font-size: 14px;"><storng>Ejecutivo</storng>:<t t-esc="seller"/></span>
                 </h3>
               <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                   <thead>
                       <th style="with:30%">Date</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Folio</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Remitente</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Consignatario</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Destino</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Volumen</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Peso_Bruto</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Factura</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Monto Fact</th>
                   </thead>
                   <t t-foreach="seller_id" t-as="seller">
                       <tr>
                           <td><span  t-esc="seller['date']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['name']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['partner']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['consignee']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['country']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['volume']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['gross']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['freight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="seller['invoice']"/></td>
                       </tr>
                   </t>
               </table>
               </t>
               <t t-if=" type == 'Country'">
           <h3>
               <span style="font-size: 14px;"><storng>Destino</storng>:<t t-esc="seller_name"/></span>
           </h3>
               <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                   <thead>
                       <th style="with:30%">Date</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Folio</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Remitente</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Consignatario</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Destino</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Volumen</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Peso_Bruto</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Factura</th>
                       <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Monto Fact</th>
                   </thead>
                   <t t-foreach="country_arrival" t-as="country">
                       <tr>
                           <td><span t-esc="country['date_order']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['name']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['partner_id']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['consignee_id']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['country_arrival']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['volume']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['gross_weight']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['freight_type']"/></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="country['invoice_amount_assured']"/></td>
                       </tr>
                   </t>
               </table>
               </t>
           </div>
           <div class="footer o_standard_footer" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
               <div class="row text-center">
                   <div class="col col-12 text-center">
                       <ul class="list-inline">
                           <li class="list-inline-item">Page:</li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">
                               <span class="page"/>
                           </li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">/</li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">
                               <span class="topage"/>
                           </li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </t>
</template>
</odoo>
```

y asi es como tengo esructurado el reporte solo que en cuestion de la variable que tengo en executive en la parte de date es donde manda el error pero el error lo esta mandando en la interfaz mas no lo esta mandando en la terminal

Comment: Comprueba esta sintaxis: `storng>Ejecutivo</storng>`, ¿no será `strong`?...

Comment: @FranciscoJavier ya hice el cambio pero paro manda ese error de que el keyerror:date